# Re-directing Help>Manual Menu to Local Drive

Tags: interface, documentation

I've downloaded the Manual pages to my Hard Drive and would like to access them via the Help>Manual menu. Is there a way to do this either through Prefs or the source code?

Thanks.

Comment: This is certainly possible be modifying the source code, unfortunately this isn't configurable through the user preferences. The operator `WM_OT_url_open_preset` is implemented in [`wm.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/wm.py$850).

Comment: Writing an add-on is of course another possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can see to achieve this.

## 1 Manually edit the UI script

Either manually edit the `space_topbar.py` topbar UI file traditionally found at `Blender_2.82\2.82\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_topbar.py` and type in an entry there to link to your local file.

You can optionally remove the online manual entry from there and replace it with an instance of `wm.url_open` operator pointing to your local file. Just copy one of the existing templates and modify it to your own use.

This is a quick and dirty solution, allows removing the existing entry, but is less maintainable, since it will likely not survive a software update nor is it easy to port to other installations.

## 2 Create a script or addon

Create a script that registers a new menu entry with a link to your own file. Easiest is probably to use `wm.url_open` operator pointing to your local file.

[image]

```
import bpy

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
            "wm.url_open", text="Local Maual", icon='HELP',
        ).url = "Z:/Applications/Blender/Documentation/Blender_Manual.pdf"


def register():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_help.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_help.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

As far as I know this won't allow removing the existing entry, but you can have the addon under, several instances, and can easily be reinstalled after software updates.